# how to organize the output of MLE using R

Tags: r, mle

I wrote down this function for MLE estimation and then I apply it for different settings of parameters.
Finally, I bind all results for an output.
But is not working i have problem with the output and also I need to organize the output like the attached image using R program.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4zEf.png)
could some one help me please?
What should I fix and how can I print the results like the picture attached.

thank you in advance

```
rbssn<- function(n,alpha,beta)
{
  if(!is.numeric(n)||!is.numeric(alpha)||!is.numeric(beta))
  {stop("non-numeric argument to mathematical function")}
  if(alpha<=0){ stop("alpha must be positive")}
  if(beta<=0) { stop("beta must be positive") }
  z      <- rnorm(n,0,1)
  r      <- beta*((alpha*z*0.5)+sqrt((alpha*z*0.5)^2+1))^2
  return(r)
}

#Function
mymle <- function(n,alpha,beta,rep)
{
  theta=c(alpha,beta) # store starting values
  #Tables
  LHE=array(0, c(2,rep));
  rownames(LHE)= c("MLE_alpha", "MLE_beta")
  #Bias
  bias= array(0, c(2,rep));
  rownames(bias)= c("bias_alpha", "bias_beta")
  #Simulation
  set.seed(1)
  #Loop
  for(i in 1:rep){
    myx <- exp(-rbssn(n, alpha, beta))
    Score <- function(x) {
      y <- numeric(2)
      y[1] <- (-n/x[1])*(1+2/(x[1]^2)) - (1/(x[2]*x[1]^3))*sum(log(myx)) - (x[2]/(x[1]^3))*sum(1/log(myx))
      y[2] <- -(n/(2*x[2])) + sum((1/(x[2]-log(myx)))) - (1/(2*(x[1]^2)*(x[2]^2)))*sum(log(myx)) + (1/(2*x[1]^2))*sum(1/(log(myx)))
      y
    }
    Sin <- c(alpha,beta)
    mle<- nleqslv(Sin, Score, control=list(btol=.01))[1]
    LHE[i,]= mle
    bias[i,]= c(mle[1]-theta[1], mle[2]-theta[2])
  }
  
  # end for i
  #Format results
  L <-round(apply(LHE, 1, mean), 3) # MLE  of all the applied iterations  
  bs <-round(apply(bias,1, mean),3) # bias of all the applied iterations 
  row<- c(L, bs)
  #Format a label
  lab <- paste0('n= ',n,';',' alpha= ',alpha,';',' beta= ',beta)
  row2 <- c(lab,row)
  row2 <- as.data.frame(t(row2))
  return(row2)
}

#Bind all
#Example 1
ex1 <- mymle(n = 20,alpha = 1,beta = 0.5,rep = 100)
ex2 <- mymle(n = 50,alpha = 2,beta = 0.5,rep = 100)
ex3 <- mymle(n = 100,alpha = 3,beta = 0.5,rep = 100)
#Example 2
ex4 <- mymle(n = 20,alpha = 0.5,beta = 0.5,rep = 100)
ex5 <- mymle(n = 50,alpha = 0.5,beta = 1,rep = 100)
ex6 <- mymle(n = 100,alpha = 0.5,beta = 1,rep = 100)
df <- rbind(ex1,ex2,ex3,ex4,ex5,ex6)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The stargazer package turns tables and other objects into latex tables, maybe it can help you

Comment: You may want to try r package `xtable`. Check out the gallery here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf